# Import will not give correct response

Tags: import

I am trying to import a skill that my friend has in test mode.He has sent me the beta test link to try it.

I wanted to add some other information to it, as we both want to try things together.

He has given me access to his git file.

I am trying to import it via this method..
Import an Alexa-hosted skill from a public Git project
To import an Alexa-hosted skill from a public Git repository

*Open the Alexa developer console and log in.
Click Create Skill. The Create a new skill page appears.
For Skill name, type a name.
For Default language, choose a language.
For Choose a model to add to your skill, select Custom.
For Choose a method to host your skill's backend resources, select Alexa-Hosted (Node.js) or Alexa-Hosted (Python).
Click Create Skill. The Choose a template to add to your skill page appears.
Click Import skill. The Import skill dialog appears.
Enter the .git link to the Git repository that contains the skill that you want to import.
Click Continue. The message Creating your Alexa-hosted skill appears. If Alexa validates that the Git repository contains an Alexa skill that it can import, Alexa creates your Alexa-hosted skill.*

I do all the above, at the start I insert a name, choose a Primary Locale English (AU) as his was done, select NEXT, select MOvies & TV, in model I select CUSTOM, I select SYNCH LOCALES, in hosting, there is a blue border around Alexa-hosted (Node.js), I then select NEXT. The following menu has the blue border around Start from Scratch, and  and has a tick in Movies & TV, I then click IMPORT SKILL, it asks me for the git file address which I insert and press IMPORT.

I then see
*Creating your Alexa hosted skill.

It will take about a minute.

Preparing the code editor...*

Eventually I get Building your skill page with all four steps given a green tick.

I click the SAVE button

The skill is there in My Skills page, showing a green dot, In Dev.

I then click on it's name on the same page, and it sends me to the next page

I then go to the Invocations tab,select it,then select the tab select Skill Invocation Name
In the field area, I enter the name and I then click the SAVE button

The next propmt says to BUILD again
I then get a popup saying
*Skill Saved Successfully
Dismiss
The skill has been saved without errors. The skill must be successfully built for changes to take effect.*

I then go to the right, and click the correct language, and then select BUILD skill
The next popup says
Build Completed
ViewDismiss
Build was successful for xxxxx xxxxx

It processes through, and builds it

In the simulator, I put it test mode, DEVELOPER
I set the language to English (AU)
In the box, I type in Alexa, open xxxxxx me (the invocation name I gave it)
The result I always get is
"There was an error with the request, please try again. "

Could someone please advise what step I am not doing correctly please?

Thanks

I was expecting it to say ok or similar, opening xxx xxx